# How can I use firebase's language code (myFirebase.auth().languageCode) in my action link URL in Firebase Authentication email template?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

So, my website, which is built using ReactJS, provides multi-language support and my routes are formatted in this manner:

> `http://localhost:3000/<alpha-2-country-code>/<action>`

I am trying to use Firebase Authentication to verify the email address that is provided by the user during sign up. This is the verify email link that I got from Firebase Authentication:

> http://localhost:3000/new-account?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=XXX&apiKey=XXX&lang=fr

My current React Project setup is that I am going to redirect users to an Error Page 404 when the **alpha-2-country-code** is not specified before the **action**.

My question is, is there a way to extract the **fr** from the *myFirebase.auth().languageCode* so that I can append it to my action link URL in Firebase Authentication email template? I couldn't find anything related to this in the official documentation.

The action link URL that i expect Firebase to produce is

> http://localhost:3000/fr/new-account?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=XXX&apiKey=XXX&lang=fr

Thanks in advance!

***(Edited on 31st of Jan 2020)***

Frankly, I already have the email action handler set up because I am using `myFirebase.auth().applyActionCode(actionCode)` to verify the user's email.

So, my current implementation requires me to set the action link URL to `http://localhost:3000/en/new-account?mode=<action>&oobCode=<code>&lang=fr` by default and it is going to get redirected to `http://localhost:3000/fr/new-account?mode=<action>&oobCode=<code>&lang=fr` because the lang is equal to ***fr*** and not the default ***en***.

I am just wondering if there is a better way of doing this because this link `https://.../en/auth/...&lang=fr` seems a bit counterintuitive as it is showing 2 conflicting languages.

It would be great if Firebase can expose more "firebase-defined" variables in the "customize action link URL" other than appending action, oobcode, and lang behind automatically because not all developers like the idea of having everything crammed in the query string.

I don't see why this leeway would jeopardize security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if anyone of you guys wonders what I did.

So, I wrote a feature request to Firebase support and this was the last email I got from their support team.

> Hello Erwin
>
> Unfortunately there is no more customization but the one that I've shared with you, however I made sure to raise a feature request, asking to add more customization features to the email action links and handlers
>
> Our engineers will certainly consider adding this to Firebase Authentication, keep an eye on the Firebase Release Notes to be informed of the latest from Firebase. Thanks again for sharing your thoughts!
>
> Please write back if you have any other consult.
>
> Cheers, X

At this point of time, I am still relying on the workaround solution that I have mentioned in my question. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Auth should already append the language code to your verification email link.
This is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler#create_the_email_action_handler_page).

```
firebase.auth().languageCode = 'fr';
firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
  .then(() => {
    // Email verification should be sent and the link will have &lang=fr
    // appended.
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Error occurred.
  });
```

Comment: Thanks bojell for the response. That is in fact what i currently have now. I have edited my question to elucidate what I was trying to convey. Thanks!